# R installation of package "BRugs" is failing for Windows 11 64 bit installation

Tags: r, installation, package

Hi so i'm trying to install R package "BRugs" and it is having an issue finding the Makeconf file.   I do have Rtools installed

```
Sys.which("make")
                                   make 
"C:\\RBUILD~1\\4.2\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```

My R_HOME is located here

```
 R.home(component = 'home')
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2"
```

But i guess this install can not find the MakeConf file within "etc" folder?

```
* installing *source* package 'BRugs' ...
** package 'BRugs' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
  running 'src/Makefile.win' ...
Makefile.win:1: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf'.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'BRugs'
* removing 'C:/Users/antho/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2.2/BRugs'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘BRugs’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo58u6i\downloaded_packages’
>
```

```
 install.packages("C:/Users/antho/Downloads/BRugs_0.9-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/antho/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'BRugs' ...
** package 'BRugs' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
  running 'src/Makefile.win' ...
Makefile.win:1: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf'.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'BRugs'
* removing 'C:/Users/antho/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2.2/BRugs'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/antho/Downloads/BRugs_0.9-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The error is related to this path "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/i386/"

```
list.dirs(paste0(R.home(component='home'),"/etc"))
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc"     "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/x64"
```

it looks like my  etc folder is missing the expected "i386" folder?  any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Do i need to edit my .Rprofile.site  file?

Comment: R-core stopped including `i386` (32-bit) as a target in R-4.2.0 (see [`NEWS`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) and scroll down to 4.2.0). Since it appears that BRugs has [hard-coded the `i386/Makeconf`](https://github.com/cran/BRugs/blob/master/src/Makefile.win#L1) in its makefile, I suggest this is a bug in the package itself. Your options? (1) downgrade R to 4.1.x; (2) download the source, manually change all references of `i386` to `x64` and cross your fingers, though it does say it (only) works _"in 32-bit R under Windows"_; or (3) wait for an update.

Comment: On #3 above ... most of the code hasn't really had any changes in the last 5 years. If Uwe (the author) had the intention of porting to 64-bit R, there has been ample opportunity to do so, suggesting you might be stuck with R-4.1 for a bit. Really, though, Uwe is the only person who can comment on if/when the package will be updated for R-4.2. I don't know if/where there is a repo for this, I don't know where to submit bug reports other than via email (listed in the package description).

Comment: so i'm getting a UCRT error when changing the Makefile path to x64 "Error in install.packages : package ‘BRugs-master’ not installed because it is not built for UCRT" so i don't think it was built for 64 bit.  even the news says it is ok for 64bit windows

Comment: Okay, I missed that portion of the package NEWS, I apologize, I was stemming off of the (perhaps out-dated) `DESCRIPTION` (and the misinterpretation of "beta" for 64-bit). Okay, try commenting out that first line that references `i386`, I believe there have been many efforts to reduce special-handling needed for R under windows.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I have a 64-bit machine can I just install a 32 bit our version and run that? I will try your suggestion up above

Comment: You can try R-4.1 (64-bit, since the package says it supports it), or R-4.1 (32-bit) (should work fully). (You won't get R-4.2 to work, since from the NEWS it explicitly says "*Support for 32-bit builds has been dropped"*.)

Comment: How do I find the beta version of this package? Do I need to install Devel r version

Comment: I know nothing about the package other than what I see on its [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BRugs/), and from the CRAN repo https://github.com/cran/BRugs; the repo gives you nothing more than the CRAN page itself, since the repo is updated when the package is updated, nothing special about it. I suspect the author's use of "beta" was purely to indicate that their experience in 64-bit R was not high so it has been under-tested. Sorry, I'm no pro on that package, I suggest you reach out to the author.